# Getting series of SQL warnings: "relation <table> does not exist, skipping"

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I don't know if it's something to worry about but as the server starts up I am getting a series of these warnings:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : relation "app_user__user_group" does not exist, skipping
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : relation "app_user__user_group" does not exist, skipping
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : relation "google_place" does not exist, skipping
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
 ...
```

I can't say that this is causing an issue - so far everything works - but I'd like to understand what's going on here.

This is the configuration I am using:

```py
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
# Because detection is disabled you have to set correct dialect by hand.
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test-db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
#spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
  # update
  # create-drop
```

---

Here, as an example, is the `@Entity` for `google_place`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "google_place")
public class GooglePlace extends AbstractTimestampEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "place_id")
    private Place place;

    @Column(name = "google_place_id", unique = true)
    private String googlePlaceId;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Place getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(Place place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public String getGooglePlaceId() {
        return googlePlaceId;
    }

    public void setGooglePlaceId(String googlePlaceId) {
        this.googlePlaceId = googlePlaceId;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with the schema generation and incorrect configuration of your entities. Can you post your entities with their annotations and any other schema related config?

Comment: @niekname I have added the entity `GooglePlace` - the configuration I posted is already all there is - I'm not aware of any additional configurations. I also checked all my Spring configuration Java classes - I am not setting up anything by hand there.

Answer (score 7):

The error occurs when the database tries to drop the older objects.
You can check the exact moment when it happens with `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`, however, if you change `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` instead of `create-drop` you will not see those warnings anymore because it will no attempt to drop nonexistent objects.

From [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl):

> `create` Database dropping will be generated followed by database
>   creation.
>
> `create-drop` Drop the schema and recreate it on SessionFactory startup.
>   Additionally, drop the schema on SessionFactory shutdown.